# Lightning Quick Action Error on IPad Only... Works on Phone and Desktop

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

I have a lightning component in a quick action that works fine on IOS for phone and Desktop but fails to open from the IPad. The error thrown is the following:

```
Action failed: forceChatter:lightningComponent$controller$doInit [Unable to evaluate code at: components/c/OrderHistoryLightningComponent.js]
quickActionHandlerHelper.js failed to create component - forceChatter:lightningComponent
```

I am not using Chatter at all in this component, maybe the API is used on mobile to render components, I am not sure. Again, this component works fine on IPhone and desktop. My SF1 is up to date on the IPad also.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with the older IPads... the one throwing the error is a 3rd generation model that is running the latest version of SF1. Only the quick action containing the custom lightning component is throwing the error. Other quick actions work fine. Just tested this on a newer model IPad and didn't hit the error.